# C++ manage heap/pointers in a singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a singleton with attributes which are pointers.

How do I prevent a memory leak when I no longer use it i.e. when the last reference to my instance is popped off the stack frame?

Does the destructor get called each time a reference gets poped off the stack?

```
A &A::getInstance()
{
static A instance;  // does this get deleted at any point?
return instance;
}
```

Comment: References don't have destructors, so no.  The instance will get destructed sometime after main ends.

Comment: Regarding the comment in the code-snippet, the answer is yes. The object will get destructed when the program ends.

Comment: So is there any way to know when to delete pointer attributes of my singleton class? or does the singleton have to live for the whole execution of the program?

Comment: @ovg, that's too broad a question. When you delete the objects to which the singleton has pointers is a policy decision. Most of the time, it should be OK to delete them in the destructor of the the singleton.

Comment: Sounds like you should explain more of your goal. Someone may suggest an alternative.

Comment: This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2713/singleton-design-pattern (maybe deinitialization-safe singleton is what you need?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton object will exist for the lifetime of the program and will be destroyed some time after `main` ends. At that point it's destructor will be invoked.

Here you may `delete` your raw pointers (or if using smart, you can set to `nullptr` or call `reset`).

This can be seen in action with the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo(std::string const& name = "Unknown")
        : m_sName{ name }
    {
        std::cout << m_sName << " is created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << m_sName << " is being destroyed" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string m_sName;
};

class Singleton
{
public:

    static Singleton& Get()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    ~Singleton()
    {
        delete m_RawFoo;
        m_SmartFoo = nullptr;
    }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }

protected:

private:

    Singleton()
    {
        m_RawFoo   = new Foo{ "Raw Foo" };
        m_SmartFoo = std::make_shared<Foo>("Shared Foo");
    }

    Foo* m_RawFoo;
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_SmartFoo;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting main..." << std::endl;

    Singleton::Get().print();
    Singleton::Get().print();

    std::cout << "Ending main..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Starting main...
Raw Foo is created
Shared Foo is created
Hello World
Hello World
Ending main...
Raw Foo is being destroyed
Shared Foo is being destroyed
```

Comment: There's no need to set a smart pointer to null or use `reset`, the smart pointer destructor will take care of that.

Comment: True, I am just in the habit of doing it manually. Suppose its a hold-over from having to `delete` (or in D3D11 calling `Release`).

Comment: This is great. thank you. I didn't really know much about smart pointers until now. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) for singletons. The following is a singleton which is alive only while there are references to it. Note that this is not entirely thread-safe. If you want thread-safety, you'll need some additional logic (probably a lock) in `GetInstance`.

```
#include <memory>

class MySingleton
{
    // singleton
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> GetInstance();
private:
    static std::weak_ptr<MySingleton> instance__;

    // lifecycle
private:
    MySingleton();
public:
    ~MySingleton();

    // delete the copy constructor, move constructor, copy operator and move operator
private:
    MySingleton(const MySingleton&) = delete;
    MySingleton(MySingleton&&) = delete;
    MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&) = delete;
    MySingleton& operator=(MySingleton&&) = delete;
};

std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> MySingleton::GetInstance()
{
    auto instance = instance__.lock();
    if (!instance) {
        instance.reset(new MySingleton);
        instance__ = instance;
    }
    return instance;
}

std::weak_ptr<MySingleton> MySingleton::instance__;

MySingleton::MySingleton()
{
    // initialization logic here
}

MySingleton::~MySingleton()
{
    // clean-up logic here
}
```

Here's some sample client code:

```
int main()
{
    // proper usage -- store the reference in a stack variable for the duration of its use
    {
        auto instance = MySingleton::GetInstance();
        instance->doSomething();
        instance->doSomethingElse();
        // instance shared_ptr will be destructed automatically,
        // which will then destruct the MySingleton instance
    }

    // BAD USAGE -- failing to store the reference will cause a new instance to be created and destroyed with each call
    {
        MySingleton::GetInstance()->doSomething();
        MySingleton::GetInstance()->doSomethingElse();
    }

    // proper usage -- store the reference in a struct or class whose lifecycle is managed appropriately
    {
        // this class takes a shared reference and stores it
        class Foo
        {
        public:
            Foo(const std::shared_ptr<MySingleton>& dependency) : dependency_(dependency) { }
        private:
            std::shared_ptr<MySingleton> dependency_;
        };

        // this instance will store a shared reference
        auto f = new Foo(MySingleton::GetInstance());

        // when the destructor is invoked, the shared_ptr will be destructed,
        // which will then destruct the MySingleton instance
        delete f;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but I realize my question wasn't entirely clear. I was asking about pointer attributes... but this may also be useful for what I'm doing anyhow! thanks ;)